# Codeigniter 4.0.4 deploy on shared hosting error

Tags: codeigniter

I trying to deploy my codeigniter 4 app on shared hosting cpanel.

I already follow tutorial from internet.

And I got error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> CodeIgniter\locale_set_default() in
> /home/myhost/server_ci4/system/CodeIgniter.php:184 Stack trace: #0
> /home/myhost/server_ci4/system/bootstrap.php(181):
> CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->initialize() #1
> /home/myhost/public_html/ci4/index.php(36):
> require('/home/myhost/...') #2 {main} thrown in
> /home/myhost/server_ci4/system/CodeIgniter.php on line 184

I dont understand the error, how to fix this? so it will run well

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found it, there is a bug ini `codeigniter v 4.0.4`.

how to solve that is :

open : `/system/Codeigniter.php`

on line 181 : `public function initialize()` update the function to :

```
/**
     * Handles some basic app and environment setup.
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        // Set default locale on the server
        if( function_exists('locale_set_default' ) ) :
            locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
        endif; 

        // Set default timezone on the server
        date_default_timezone_set($this->config->appTimezone ?? 'UTC');

        // Define environment variables
        $this->detectEnvironment();
        $this->bootstrapEnvironment();

        // Setup Exception Handling
        Services::exceptions()
                ->initialize();

        $this->initializeKint();

        if (! CI_DEBUG)
        {
            // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
            \Kint::$enabled_mode = false;
            // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
        }
    }
```

the solution in :

```
        if( function_exists('locale_set_default' ) ) :
            locale_set_default($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
        endif;
```